# Make: splitting a file and parallelization

Tags: parallel-processing, makefile, bioinformatics

My bioinformatics workflow processes the data in parallel using the option '-j' of **make**.

```
mutations.tsv : file1.data file2.data file3.data
       find-mutations $^ > $@

file1.data: raw1.txt
        (....)
(...)
```

**mutations.tsv** is a bottleneck but things could be faster if

1) I could find the number of distinct chromosomes in the file1.data file2.data

2) run 'find-mutations' for each chromosome

3) merge all the results in 'mutations.tsv'

something like:

```
mutations.tsv : file1.data file2.data file3.data
       for CHROM in `cut -d ' ' -f 1 $< | sort -u` ; do grep $${CHROM} $^| find-mutations -  >> $@ ; done
```

How can I change this to create a parallelized workflow ?

Note: this makefile is itself generated on the fly. I don't know the number of chromosomes before creating the Makefile, so I cannot use the following solution:

```
mutations.tsv  : chr1.tsv chr2.tsv chr3.tsv chr4.tsv
            cat $^ > $@

chr1.tsv: file1.data file2.data file3.data
        grep chr1 $^| find-mutations -  > $@

chr2.tsv: ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution that you said can't be done is on the right track. You could use `wildcard` to have make pick up the variable number of chr files. For example:

```
chrs = $(wildcard chr*.tsv)
files = $(wildcard file*.data)

mutations.tsv : $(chrs)
            cat $^ > $@

$(chrs): $(files)
        grep chr1 $^| find-mutations -  > $@
```